# Send message to all running instance of windows app

Tags: .net, winforms, message

I have a windows application which is published on a website and can be installed by users using 'Click once' method.

I have several users, who will be working on the app at any given point of time.

I'm thinking of implementing a Messaging system, wherein system administrator can broadcast messages to all the currently running instance of this application (online...)...

I could set up a timer to check for updates from database at regular intervals...  But, I feel it is a total waste of resources...

Is there an alternate way for it...  like, will I be able to trigger messages from Database to all the applications...

PS : It would be great if possible to send messages even to the apps that are running offline (as they would be accessing the DB)

Hope I made it clear... Please let me know if otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to get into listening on sockets or whatever, I'd say that using a web service to check for messages in a Database is an OK alternative.

That way, you don't have to care how many clients are out there.  Just keep the query lightweight and keep the table clean and it shouldnt be that much of a waste of resources.  Use a WCF service to access the DB, even turn on compression, and youll find the whole round trip only a few KB and a small light query.

Comment: Thanks... I will go that way itself.